# How can I create a new Gnome Terminal profile?

Tags: gnome-terminal

As the title says, how can I create a new Gnome Terminal profile?

Comment: This seems like a trivial question, but it's in response to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/598958/301745), which didn't answer its question, but 4 people found it useful (i.e. 4 people upvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnome Terminal, click "File" → "New Profile"

For more details, see [Gnome Terminal help - Manage profiles](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-profiles.html.en#new-profile)